# Using a for loop to append multiple images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I just want a for loop to print the same image 10 times without manually creating 10 's since I  may want to append more later. I have used this exact same code in other projects and it has worked but for some reason it won't work this time.

The image html is:

```
<img id = "crate" src="img/Acrate.png"/>
```

Here's my code:

```
function drawCrates (){
                        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                            var crate_img = document.createElement("IMG");
                            crate_img.setAttribute("src", "images/Acrate.png");
                            document.getElementById("crate").appendChild(crate_img);
                        }
}
drawCrates();
```

Comment: you should append elements to those element which can contain other elements. Like you can append all the images to a div.

Comment: change that `#crate` element to a div and this will work

Comment: thanks, it worked! Appending it to the div worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the image element to such element that can hold other elements. Try this,

***HTML :***

```
<div id="imageDiv">
</div>
```

***javaScript :***

```
function drawCrates (){
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var crate_img = document.createElement("IMG");
        crate_img.setAttribute("src", "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-PfTrZFQ8c4U/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAA0/IJXxoIqKNSU/photo.jpg");
        document.getElementById("imageDiv").appendChild(crate_img);
    }
}
drawCrates();
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/ed4uj08s/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) for speed, and then just cloning the node as you need it. The code looks like the following:

```
function drawCrates (){
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        img = document.createElement('img');

    img.setAttribute("src", "images/Acrate.png");
    fragment.appendChild(img);
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        fragment.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
    }

    document.body.appendChild(fragment);
}
drawCrates();
```

Your issue stems from trying to append an element as a child of an `<img>` element, which is invalid. The code you have:

```
<img id="crate" ... />
```

When you run the code `document.getElementById("crate")` you are grabbing the `<img>` element, and it is not possible to append child elements to an `<img>`.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue of why appending to a `img` tag doesn't work.