# How to use javascript add image with link in specific explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-brackets

I want to add an image with link only when I in `Safari`, and this is my html and js.I am new for javascript.

```js
var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.match("Safari") ;
    
if (isSafari) {
    alert('You are using Safari or Google');
        
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src','images/ar_but.png'); 

    document.getElementsByClassName('gallery').getElementsByClassName('thumbnail').getElementById('AddImageInhere').appendChild(image); 
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Container -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icon01.jpg" alt="" width="2000" class="cards" /></a>
        <h4>TITLE</h4>
        <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" id="AddImageInhere"> !!!</a>
        <p class="tag">HTML, CSS, JS, WordPress</p>
        <p class="text_column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>  
    </div> 
  </div> 
<!-- Main Container Ends -->
```

But this code doesn't work. I want to add an image like right one at !!!  here the result : [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ymZg.png) [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iADuW.jpg)

It appear the alert. But at !!! . There's no image.

I use brackets. Thank for reading.

edit:
Here is the error.

```
ERROR: 'navigator' is not defined. [no-undef]   var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.match("Safari");
ERROR: 'alert' is not defined. [no-undef]   alert('You are using Safari or Google');
ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]    var image = document.createElement('img');
ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]    document.getElementById('AddImageInhere').appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the first 2 `getElementsByClassName()` functions. You can't chain them since they return a nodelist. Nodelists don't have the `getElementsByClassName()` function.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

```js
var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.match("Safari");
if (isSafari) {
  alert('You are using Safari or Google');
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.setAttribute('src', 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
  document.getElementById('AddImageInhere').appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/icon01.jpg" alt="" width="2000" class="cards" /></a>
      <h4>TITLE</h4>
      <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" id="AddImageInhere"> !!!</a>
      <p class="tag">HTML, CSS, JS, WordPress</p>
      <p class="text_column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320852/how-to-use-javascript-add-image-with-link-in-specific-explorer/58320966#
  </div>
</div>
```

For multiple images I suggest using QuerySelector all and create a new image for each append.

```js
var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.match("Safari");
if (isSafari) {
  alert('You are using Safari or Google');
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.AddImageInhere').forEach((el) => { 
    el.appendChild(getImage()); 
  });
}

function getImage() {
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.setAttribute('src', 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
  return image;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/icon01.jpg" alt="" width="2000" class="cards" /></a>
      <h4>TITLE</h4>
      <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" class="AddImageInhere"> !!!</a>
      <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" class="AddImageInhere"> !!!</a>
      <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" class="AddImageInhere"> !!!</a>
      <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" class="AddImageInhere"> !!!</a>
      <p class="tag">HTML, CSS, JS, WordPress</p>
      <p class="text_column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320852/how-to-use-javascript-add-image-with-link-in-specific-explorer/58320966#
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but there still the same, here is my [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/9OIL8rK.png) . I wonder if it's because of the red error beside the code.

Comment: @蚵仔麵線 Don't post code as screenshots. Just edit your question so you provide a reproducible problem. As you can see in my snippet, your code works fine when removing the chained functions.

Comment: I sorry for that. But It doesn't work in bracket. I already remove the chained functions. The result is same as beginning.

Comment: Okay ,I post it.

Comment: @蚵仔麵線 The problem is not in the code but in brackets. I never worked with brackets so I don't know what's wrong except that it the error messages tells you that standard objects (document, alert, etc) that are normally available for usages in most browsers are not available in brackets.

Comment: @ Mark Baijens  Yes,you are right. It's work on codepen if I put the image on imgur and link it,but it only work on the first "AddImageInhere" . I guess this function only return the first element. I try to find another way to solve it because I want all of them be changed.

Comment: @蚵仔麵線 That's because you use the `getElementById()` which only returns one element because id's need to be unique. For multiple elements assign a class like `addImageHereClass` to the `<a>` element and use `document.querySelectorAll('.addImageHereClass').forEach((el) => {el.appendChild(image);});`

Comment: I use it, but the image only appear at last one . I try it in snippet and codepen. The result like [this](https://i.imgur.com/VeL0Pnj.png). The see in AR image. I want four of div appear that image.

Comment: I find out the solution!! I add `.cloneNode(true)`  the code is `document.querySelectorAll('.AddImageInhere').forEach((el) => {el.appendChild(image.cloneNode(true));});`  I get this thought from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884556/12158209). Thank you for helping!

Comment: @蚵仔麵線 Yeah, the same image was appended so in the end it was only displayed in the last element because the append function removes it from the previous location if it had one. I made a snippet with a function that creates a new image every time, but your solution of cloning it works perfectly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Function getElementsByClassName() returns collection. You can't call next getElementsByClassName() on the collection. Just use querySelectorAll instead this functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You are part of my solution.